Husky (v8) - multiple issues with setting up pre-commit (error: cannot spawn and no pre-commit file created)
On a new project, I run:
npm install --save-dev husky

Then:
npx husky init

Expected outcome (as per docs @ https://typicode.github.io/husky/get-started.html)
"The init command simplifies setting up husky in a project. It creates a pre-commit script in .husky/ and updates the prepare script in package.json."
What happens:
Console logs the below lines, and no folder is created:
Usage:
  husky install [dir] (default: .husky)
  husky uninstall
  husky set|add <file> [cmd]

Next, as per output from above, I run:
npx husky install

This installs a .husky folder in my project root directory, which has a .gitignore file and a "husky.sh" file in it. There is no pre-commit file created.
Try again to run:
npx husky init 

Afterwards, but this does nothing other than logging the same help text to the console.
In .git/hooks folder, I cannot see a pre-commit file (only pre-commit.sample).
I still have this in my package.json file:
"lint-staged": {
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run tidy",
      "npm run test"
  ]
}

Along with this under my scripts:
"pre-commit": "lint-staged"

But I am wondering whether or not I actually still need these? There is no mention of them in the current Husky docs. There isn't actually a lot in the Husky docs...
I manually add a pre-commit file in the .husky directory, with the following command in it:
npm run lint

Which runs my eslint script. But I then get the following error:
 error: cannot spawn .husky/pre-commit: No such file or directory

Any advice on what to do or how to actually use this package?
